# In ag-grid, what does the option angularCompileRows do?

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I was trying to get individual cells in an **ag-grid** to fire **ng-click** events against a scope method in a parent controller today and tried a ton of different things. After looking at some working code people had posted, I noticed that everyone was setting **angularCompileRows** to **true** in the **gridOptions**. I tried turning **angularCompileRows** on in my own code and it worked! ng-click fired and called the controller method.

My question is: what exactly does **angularCompileRows** in **ag-grid** do? I can only find one reference to it in the official documentation (in the code examples on [this page](https://ag-grid.com/angular-grid-cell-rendering/index.php)) and it's very light on explanation. I'm wondering if there are any side effects/downsides to turning this option on.

Comment: Basically it just makes Angular add the rows to the digest cycle so that it checks for changes If I understand correctly.

Comment: The docuemntaion linked from the question now longer even mentions `angularCompileRows` :-(  Is it the case that this must be set to `true`, otherwise clicking any rendered button will have no effect? Could you please post an explanatory answer, in order to help others? Thanx a 1,000,000

Answer (score 1):

After googling a bit, I found [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-grid/#turn-on-angular-compile) in the documentation.

From what I understand, by default ag-grid is built using raw JavaScript for performance purposes. However, if you are willing to take the performance hit, you can set **angularCompileRows** to **true** and it will create a new scope per row and you will be able to leverage AngularJS inside Cell Renderers. I think this is why the AngularJS ng- events don't work unless you set **angularCompileRows** to **true**